# How to setup more than one team admin to make adhoc distribution builds for TestFlightApp?

Tags: certificate, ios-provisioning, provisioning-profile, ad-hoc-distribution, testflight

I am using TestFlightApp to distribute test adhoc builds of my app to my entire team, I have three team admins who need to be able to put up new builds to test flight app.  Unfortunately, Apple only allows one team admin to make distribution builds so two of my team members can't put new builds up -- which is very inconvenient.

How can I setup my distribution certificate for the team so that more than one team admin can successfully setup a valid signing system for generating adhoc distribution builds which can then be submitted to TestFlightApp?

The only idea I've had so far is to share the private team key, but I have not yet successfully gotten that to work and I haven't found any step by step instructions to help me.  All I've found is a mention in Apple Documentation that this might be possible:  [Distributing Apps](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/35-Distributing_Applications/distributing_applications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH10-SW2)

This quote from [Configuring Development and Distribution Assets](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/10-Configuring_Development_and_Distribution_Assets/identities_and_devices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH4-SW2) is the most helpful thing I've found so far, but doesn't really talk about how to setup multiple admins:

> > Safeguarding and Transferring Your Signing and Provisioning Assets
>
> Your signing and provisioning assets are the private keys,
>   certificates, and provisioning profiles you use to run iOS apps on
>   your development devices. If you need to use a Mac other than the one
>   containing your developer assets to develop iOS apps, you must
>   transfer the assets to the other Mac. You can do this in the Organizer
>   by [exporting your signing and provisioning](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-devices_organizer/articles/export_signing_assets.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010392-CH8) assets from the one Mac and
>   importing them to the other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer I've found is the one I came up with already, use these XCode Organizer instructions:

[Exporting Your Code Signing Assets to Your File System](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-devices_organizer/articles/export_signing_assets.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010392-CH8)

to create a file containing the relevant setup information.  I sent the file to the other admins, and then they import the settings into XCode Organizer using these instructions:

[Importing Your Code Signing Assets from Your File System](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-devices_organizer/articles/import_signing_assets.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010392-CH9-SW1)

so everybody is using the same private signing key for the same team distribution certificate.  This is working well for adhoc builds, I suspect it will also work for app store builds although I haven't tried it yet.